# Material ui color picker for react value validation message

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, color-picker

I am using material ui color picker: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-color-picker

```js
<ColorPicker
  name='color'
  defaultValue='#000'
  // value={this.state.color} - for controlled component
  onChange={color => console.log(color)}
 
/>
```

Is there any value validation? If user entered wrong value? How can I show error message?
I searched but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use color check manually. Define function

```
const isColor = (strColor) => {
  const s = new Option().style;
  s.color = strColor;
  return s.color !== '';
}
```

then check before value set

```
value={isColor(this.state.color)? this.state.color : '#000000'}
```

can check `onChange` too

```
onChange={
    color => {
        if (isColor(color)) {
            console.log(color);
        } else {
            console.error('Invalid Color');
            this.setState({color: '#000000'});
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: yes, I created my validation, like you suggested. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did custom validation message and seems it's working:

```js
colorChanged = (value, type) => {
  var isHex = /^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(value);
  if (value && value.length > 0 && !isHex) {
     this.setState({ [type]: true });
  } else {
     this.setState({ [type]: false });
  }
};

<Field fullWidth
       type="color"
       name="textColor"
       id="textColor"
       label="Text Color"
       onChange={(val) => this.colorChanged(val, 'textColor')}
       component={FieldWrapper} />
{this.state.textColor && <Typography color="error" className="error-color">Please enter correct Color!</Typography>}
```